# C++ - shared_ptr of abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, shared-ptr

I have the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MsgType {
public:
    virtual string getData() const = 0;
    static MsgType* getMsg();
};

class Msg1 : public MsgType {
    string getData() const override final {
        return "Msg1";
    }
};

class Msg2 : public MsgType {
    string getData() const override final {
        return "Msg2";
    }
};

queue<shared_ptr<MsgType>> allMsgs;

MsgType* MsgType::getMsg() {
    shared_ptr<MsgType> msg_sp = nullptr;
    if (!allMsgs.empty()) {
        msg_sp = allMsgs.front();
        allMsgs.pop();
    }
    if (msg_sp) {
        MsgType* mt = msg_sp.get();
        cout << "[in the method] " << mt->getData() << endl;
        return mt;
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

int main() {
    MsgType* msg1 = new Msg1();
    MsgType* msg2 = new Msg2();
    shared_ptr<MsgType> msg;
    msg.reset(msg1);
    allMsgs.push(msg);
    msg.reset(msg2);
    allMsgs.push(msg);
    MsgType* tryGetMsg = MsgType::getMsg();
    cout << "[out of the method] " << tryGetMsg->getData() << endl;
}
```

In the `MsgType::getMsg()` method I can see the output, but in the `main()` I can't. I belive that it's trying to call `MsgType::getData()` which is virtual. 
How can I get the `MsgType` outside of this method, in a way that I can access the derived class' methods?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that your call to `tryGetMsg->getData()` is invalid. Since you popped your pointer in `getMsg`, and the shared ptr `msg_sp` is destroyed at the function exit, the returned pointer points to an already destroyed object.

Comment: Return a raw pointer when not transferring ownership is okay.  Raw pointer parameter when not transferring ownership is okay.  For the other cases, use a `std::unique_ptr` (*go to* choice), or (if you have to) a `std::shared_ptr` or possibly a `std::weak_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate fix is to just return a shared_ptr from `getMsg`:

```
shared_ptr<MsgType> MsgType::getMsg() {
    shared_ptr<MsgType> msg_sp;
    if (!allMsgs.empty()) {
        msg_sp = allMsgs.front();
        allMsgs.pop();
    }
    if (msg_sp) {
        cout << "[in the method] " << msg_sp->getData() << endl;
    }
    return msg_sp;
}
```

and stop converting needlessly between smart and raw pointers.

The message object must be kept alive until the caller has finished using it. Since you're using `shared_ptr` to manage the object lifetime, you need a `shared_ptr` to continue existing as long as you want to use the object.

In general, mixing raw and smart pointers to the same objects is risky, because the smart pointers can only track the references they know about: that is, `shared_ptr` has to know *everywhere* a pointer to the object is being shared. It can only do this if every one of those pointers *is* a `shared_ptr`.

---

Note also that the easy way to diagnose object lifetime problems is to write a destructor that logs something. This brings us on to the second problem: in order for `MsgType` to be a suitable abstract base class here, it needs a virtual destructor.

Without that, the `shared_ptr` will try to destroy your object when the refcount becomes zero, but be unable (in general) to do so correctly.

```
class MsgType {
public:
    virtual ~MsgType() {}
    virtual string getData() const = 0;
};
```

---

Veering finally into code review, I intentionally omitted `getMsg` above.

Having a class static method to access a global queue is just weird. If you want to keep that layout, the `allMsgs` queue should probably be class static as well.

Instead, it's probably better to just keep a `msg_queue` object wherever you actually need it, with no statics or globals.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
MsgType* MsgType::getMsg() {
    shared_ptr<MsgType> msg_sp = nullptr;
    if (allMsgs.empty()) {
        msg_sp = allMsgs.front();
        allMsgs.pop();
    }
    if (msg_sp) {
        MsgType* mt = msg_sp.get();
        cout << "[in the method] " << mt->getData() << endl;
        return mt;
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

When `allMsgs` is not empty you you copy `front` then `pop`. At that moment there is a single `shared_ptr` managing that object: `msg_sp`. Then you retrieve a raw pointer via `get` and return that, but when the function returns the use-count decrements to `0` and the managed object is destroyed. The returned pointer is invalid.

I find your mixing of raw and `shared_ptr` a little confusing. When you have a `shared_ptr` managing the lifetime of the object then you cannot first get a raw pointer, then let the `shared_ptr` destroy the managed object and still use the raw pointer. You need to properly transfer ownership when you don't want the shared pointer to destroy the managed object.

Comment: I understood what you saying, but didn't understand how to implement that.
In other words, what is the proper way to do so?

Comment: @עתודהאקדמאית For one, stop using raw pointers. Popping the shared_ptr from the queue means its lifetime is now solely in the hands of the local `msg_sp` When that is destroyed on function return, there is no more object; the last-man-out destroys it and all you have left it a dangling pointer.

Comment: @עתודהאקדמאית wrong code is not good at explaining what you actually want to do. Maybe someone else will understand, but imho it would be better if you explain what is the actul purpose of the code.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you are mixing `std::shared_ptr` and C-style pointers this way, but let's ignore this and assume it's just as an exercise.

Having a look at the bottom half of your code (slightly reduced), we have this:

```
std::queue<std::shared_ptr<MsgType>> allMsgs;

MsgType* MsgType::getMsg();

int main() {
    MsgType* msg1 = new Msg1();
    std::shared_ptr<MsgType> msg;
    msg.reset(msg1);               // <--- 1. here, msg1 is owned by msg
    allMsgs.push(msg);             // <--- 2. now, msg1 is also owned by allMsgs
    msg.reset();                   // <--- 3. msg1 only owned by allMsgs

    MsgType* tryGetMsg = MsgType::getMsg();  // <--- see below : nobody keeping msg1 alive!
    std::cout << "[out of the method] " << tryGetMsg->getData() << std::endl;
}

MsgType* MsgType::getMsg() {
    std::shared_ptr<MsgType> msg_sp = nullptr;
    if (!allMsgs.empty()) {
        msg_sp = allMsgs.front();  // <--- 4. msg1 owned by msg_sp & allMsgs
        allMsgs.pop();             // <--- 5. msg1 owned by msg_sp only
    }
    if (msg_sp) {
        MsgType* mt = msg_sp.get();
        std::cout << "[in the method] " << mt->getData() << std::endl;
        return mt;
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}                                  // <--- 6. msg_sp destroyed... oh oh... msg1 dead :)
```

As as small addition, you can construct a shared base class pointer directly from a derived one, e.g.

```
auto msg_sp = std::shared_ptr<MsgType>(std::make_shared<Msg1>());
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue where a dangling pointer is returned

Comment: @hegel5000: That is true. I didn't change the code, just added explanations of what is happening. I was trying to explain why the print does not work. The OP claimed the "I belive that it's trying to call MsgType::getData() which is virtual."

It looked like an exercise to understand what is happening... why else return a raw ptr?